# Transforming Position in y-axis (going down) in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I want the gameobject to go down (position.y) after pressing a key instead of pressing the key repeatedly. So in my current code the object goes down(0.05f) each time I press a key. But I want it to go down (1.2) with a smooth animation when I press a key.

```
Vector2 Pos;

void Update ()
{
 Pos = transform.position;

 if(Input.anyKeyDown)
 {   
   ChangePosY();
 }
 transform.position = Pos;
}

void ChangePosY()
{
 if (Pos.y >= 1.2)
 {
  Pos.y -= 0.05f;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use smooth translation with `Vector2.Lerp()`. One new variable `isKeyPressed` to detect key pressed which is changed when target position condition meets, until it translates towards target position with 1.2 unit in y-axis/downward with 0.1 frequency. [See Lerp() Ref.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html)

```
Vector2 Pos;
bool isKeyPressed = false;

void Update()
{
    Pos = transform.position;

    if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        isKeyPressed = true;
    }

    if (isKeyPressed)
    {
        ChangePosY();
    }
    transform.position = Pos;
}

void ChangePosY()
{
    if (Pos.y >= 1.2f)
    {
        Pos = Vector2.Lerp(Pos, new Vector2(Pos.x, Pos.y - 1.2f), 0.1f);
    }
    else
    {
        isKeyPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do this with an onscreen button?

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button . Write a public method in the same script to call from button which makes `isKeyPressed` true.

Comment: I apologize I didn't mention this but instead me having to get the y position can I just increase the y position by a float.

Comment: You may keep a public or serialize-able private variable for the float representing y position. That way it doesn't have to a fixed number. You can change it on inspector as well as from other script. Private type will need to be accessed from a public method instead of direct access.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with a coroutine:

```
// Keep track of the current coroutine so we don't stack up multiple.
Coroutine translation;

void Update()
{
     if(Input.anyKeyDown)
     {
         translation = StartCoroutine(
                           TranslateTo(
                              /* Put the final position you want here */,
                              1.0f
                           )
                       ); 
     }
}

IEnumerator TranslateTo(Vector3 destination, float duration)
{
     // Stop previous coroutine if the last motion didn't finish yet.
     if(translation != null)
         StopCoroutine(translation);


     Vector3 initialPosition = transform.position;

     // Shifting the start back one frame so we move a little immediately.
     float startTime = Time.time - Time.deltaTime;
     float endTime = startTime + duration;

     while(Time.time < endTime)
     {
         float t = (Time.time - startTime)/duration;
         transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialPosition, destination, t);

         // Wait one frame, then resume here.
         yield return null;
     }

     // Ensure we finish exactly at the destination.
     transform.position = destination;

     // Clear coroutine cache to signal that we're done.
     translation = null;
}
```